# Social icons won't work in mobile and in some tablets (Link doesn't work and they don't change image on hover)

Tags: html, css

I've created some social media icons and set them up using the following html and css. They're supposed to change to a different image upon hover and are also supposed to be linking to the various social media links. However, on some tablets and mobile, it doesn't change image upon hover and doesn't go anywhere when you click it. Here's the HTML and CSS for it. There's one at the top and bottom of the page. I'm having the issue with the one at the bottom in the footer area.

HTML:

```
<div class="social-media-holder socialtop">
            <div title="Visit our Facebook page" class="social-facebook" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/ilovetennistoronto')"></div>
            <div title="Visit our Twitter page" class="social-twitter" onclick="window.open('http://www.twitter.com/ilovetennisTO')"></div>
            <div title="Visit our Google+ page" class="social-google" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/u/1/b/117545117809252336887/117545117809252336887')"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-media-holder {
  float: right;
  margin: -18px -40px 0 0;
}
.socialtop {
  top: -7px;
}
.social-facebook,
.social-google,
.social-twitter {
  background-image: url('http://www.ilovetennis.ca/wp-content/themes/I-L-T-Theme/images/button_sprite_low.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 32px;
}
.social-facebook,
.social-google,
.social-twitter {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25px;
}
.social-google {
  background-position: -621px -71px;
}
.social-twitter {
  background-position: -581px -71px;
}
.social-facebook {
  background-position: -541px -71px;
}
.social-google:hover {
  background-position: -621px -29px;
}
.social-twitter:hover {
  background-position: -581px -29px;
}
.social-facebook:hover {
background-position: -541px -29px;
}
```

Can someone please help me out? I would really appreciate it. I've been trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your div ".rt-logo-block" has a width of 100% which on small screens covers your social icons. Simply add a "float:left" on the .rt-logo-block selector for small screens and the issue is resolved

`@media only screen and (max-width:650px) {
    .rt-logo-block {
       float:right
     }
}`

should do it.

Obviously you may need to play around with the max-width value depending on your needs

In the footer the same thing is occurring when the social media icons are being overlapped by the div ".rt-grid-4.rt-alpha" the solution is to add the following css to ".social-media-holder" for small screens:

`@media only screen and (max-width:650px) {
    .social-media-holder {
        float: none;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right:0px;
        right:0px;
    }
}`

Comment: The main problem is with the ones at the bottom of the page in the footer.

Comment: It's the same issue there. you should add the following css to the .social-media-holder class:

float: none;
text-align: right;

which will give the same effect but stop the overlap from .rt-grid-4.rt-alpha

Answer (score 0):

Tablet devices don't have a hover per say.  You may have to use jQuery mobile to "fake" that effect when a user touches one of your icons.

As for why your page doesn't go anywhere when the user clicks... div elements shouldn't really have onclick events like this.  Using anchor tags is much more sensible.

```
<div class="social-media-holder socialtop">
    <a title="Visit our Facebook page" class="social-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/ilovetennistoronto" target="_blank">Facebook</a>

    <a title="Visit our Twitter page" class="social-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/ilovetennisTO" target="_blank">Twitter</a>

    <a title="Visit our Google+ page" class="social-google" href="https://plus.google.com/u/1/b/117545117809252336887/117545117809252336887" target="_blank">Google+</a>
        </div>
```

And CSS

```
.social-media-holder {
  float: right;
  margin: -18px -40px 0 0;
}
.socialtop {
  top: -7px;
}
.social-media-holder a {
  background: url('http://www.ilovetennis.ca/wp-content/themes/I-L-T-Theme/images/button_sprite_low.png') no-repeat;

  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;

  margin: 2px; /* with the display: block; float: left; below; this 2px margin will work properly now */
  text-indent: -3000px; /* hides the text of the icons, and so people with screen readers can still see your social icons */

  display: block;
  float : left; /* please note this as with inline-block would cause white space with the anchor tags on separate lines.*/
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25px;
}

/* icons */
.social-google {
  background-position: -621px -71px;
}
.social-twitter {
  background-position: -581px -71px;
}
.social-facebook {
  background-position: -541px -71px;
}

/* icons : hovers */
.social-google:hover {
  background-position: -621px -29px;
}
.social-twitter:hover {
  background-position: -581px -29px;
}
.social-facebook:hover {
background-position: -541px -29px;
}
```

Hope this helps (and works).

Comment: Checking your site (I love tennis...) your social media icons are possibly off by 1px on the vertical, hence the wiggle.  Unless intended :D